# MySQL ReGex statement

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database, preg-match

I have never come across RegEx in mySQL, In a column I have over 500 different server versions. is it possible to only fetch anything before a forward slash so that i can detect the most common servers by filtering out the versions?

```
Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Microsoft-IIS/6.0
Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)
Apache/2.2.15 (CentO
Apache/1.3.42 (Unix)
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubunt
Resin/3.0.23
Apache/2.2.0 (Linux/
```

Comment: Do you need a regex for this? It seems like 'index of' and 'substring' operations for `/` and `(` are sufficient.

Comment: Do you have a regex that will match this already?

Comment: Also: http://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here,

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(version,1,LOCATE('/', version)-1) FROM TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c826/7)

because of `DISTINCT`, only unique rows are displayed.

Comment: Wow i just searched and noticed that some of my gathered website server has "'; DROP TABLE server" could this be done purposely by webmasters?

Comment: someone has tried to mess with your database, how did you code in your php file?

Comment: Actually my database is run on my localhost, no outside access

Comment: JW can I further count instead of selecting distinct values, so that I have on one colum the distinct server and on the right the number of occurrences

Comment: i got it SELECT SUBSTRING(version,1,LOCATE('/', version)-1) as server, count(*)
FROM TableName

Comment: Look what i was able to retrieve, http://i44.tinypic.com/2zhnmtt.png how can i get rid of the empty ones

Comment: I never new sql had those capabilities, well it has all come to fruition now, I wantto show you my results, http://oi41.tinypic.com/2qcic82.jpg what do you think, is for my disertation

Answer (score 2):

In mysql regex cannot return a matched substring, but only return a boolean if the string matches a regular expression or not.

What you need is just a `SUBSTR`

```
SUBSTRING(col, 1, LOCATE('/', col) - 1)
```

but keep in mind that if there is no `/` in the string you'll end up with an empty string as a result

Comment: Yes, but that boolean can be used in a WHERE statement

Comment: @Christian Stewart: can be, so? "is it possible to only fetch anything before a forward slash"